# On What basis does the Mongo DB displays the records when used with find option?

Tags: mongodb

I am using MongoDB as  DataBase for my  application

I have a question with respect to Mongo DB find operation .

Assume if i have two / three same records  on a field say symbol  in the collection present in the Database .

db.collection.find( { "symbol": "GOOG" })

On  What basis does  the Mongo DB shows the First record ??

**Edited part**

I am having Mongo DB present in my Test Environment and as well as in Production Environment with the same data .

my question is ,

when i do

db.bios.find( { "name": "FOOGY" } )

There is a difference  in the Data that is displayed (the first record )  in two environments ??

Please let me know why there is a variation in the Data that is dislayed in two environments when issued the same commnad

db.bios.find( { "name": "FOOGY" } )

Please let me know is there any thumb rule that what record should be sown first ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you explicitly sort, it's whatever order they happen to be stored in on disk (called [natural order](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-natural-order)).  If you care what the order of the returned records is, provide the `sort` option to your `find`.

To address your updated question: yes, if you have the same docs stored in to separate MongoDB instances, they definitely can come back in a different from one another.  Even a single MongoDb instance can return the docs in a different order over time as documents are relocated on disk due to updates.

Comment: Thanks JohnnyHK , i have edited my question , to ask whether the natural order differs based on environment ??

Comment: @PreethiJain the order can be influenced by anything. Environment, other database content, current CPU and RAM usage, phase of the moon, anything. Don't rely on it.

Comment: Thanks a lot , i was thinking why it was different . so is there any way by which i can get the last updated record ?? through find option ??

Comment: Sort by the objectid? This is a clean method most of the time

Comment: My scenario is that there is a Job that will be run everyday which will either update / insert the record in MongoDb , so i need the last Updated / inserted record through find option .

Comment: @PreethiJain Then you need to add a `lastUpdated` field to your docs and update that whenever you update/insert.  Then you can sort descending on that field to find the most recently touched doc.

Comment: Yea I would use a dedicated timestamp which is modified on insert/update and queried like: `db.col.find({name: g}).sort({ts:-1}).limit(1)/batchSize(1)` That should get you your newest record.

Answer (score 0):

It returns the records in whatever order it finds them. It's not random, but it's not predictable either, and even when you find a pattern, it could suddenly be totally different for some reason. When you want a specific order, sort the results, or include an unique index in your query and use findOne().

Answer (score 0):

The documents actually come back in find order not `$natural` order and, as told, about `$natural` order, when I asked the question long ago in the Google Group, they are not the same.

The find order has an element of randomness to it but it is not completely random.