# MongoDB : How to make findAndModify returns the Last Updated Record

Tags: java, mongodb

I am new to Mongo DB and having trouble as it is behaving differently in different environments ( Dev , QA and  Production)

I am using findAndModify to Update the Records in my MongoDB .

There is a Job that runs daily which Updates /Inserts Data to Mongo DB , and i am using findAndModify to Update the Record .

But what i observed is that the first record that is returned by  findAndModify  is different in Dev , QA and Production environemnts although the three environments are  having the same Data ??

As per the Mongo DB  document , it states that findAndModify will modify the first document

Currently this is my code :

```
BasicDBObject update = new BasicDBObject();
update.append("$set", new BasicDBObject(dataformed));
coll.findAndModify(query, update);
```

Please let me know how can i make sure that , the findAndModify returns the Last Updated Record , rather than depending upon un predictable behaviour ??

**Edited Part**

I am trying to use sort for my code but it is giving me compilation errors

**coll.findAndModify(query,  sort: { rating: 1 }, update);**

I have a field called as lastUpdated which is created using System.currentTimeMilis

So can i use this lastUpdated as shown this way to get the Last Updated Record

```
coll.findAndModify(  query, 
    new BasicDBObject("sort", new BasicDBObject("lastUpdated ", -1)), 
    update);
```

Comment: There is no coll.sort , and i am using findAndModify and not find

Comment: Please see my answer here:
[Fully working method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943434/mongodbs-set-equivalent-in-its-java-driver/46728939#46728939) - Enjoy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you are using Java, so you have to construct the `sort` parameter as a `DBObject`, just like the other parameters:

```
coll.findAndModify(
    query, 
    new BasicDBObject("sort", new BasicDBObject("rating", 1)), 
    update);
```

Comment: Can i use  new BasicDBObject("sort", new BasicDBObject("lastUpdated ", -1)),   to get the Record that was last Modified using findAndModify ??

Comment: @PreethiJain If your `update` object updates `lastUpdated` to the current time, yes.

Answer (score 1):

As we already explained to you in [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13919735/on-what-basis-does-the-mongo-db-displays-the-records-when-used-with-find-option), you have to add a field to the document which contains the date it was changed and then sort by that field or you have to use a [capped collection](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Capped+Collections), because they guarantee that the insertion order is preserved.

Comment: Thanks a lot , i have a Updated at field in my collection , how can i add sort based on that  to my code ??